# Show external dll XML comments in C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, intellisense, mapwingis

I have a C++ COM application which I use in a C# application.
When placing the COM object on my WinForm two interop dlls are created by Visual Studio 2017.

Because C++ is more difficult to document I also have a second C# application which is creating two dlls with the same name as the interop dlls and also the intellisense XML-files. In this application I implement all interfaces from the COM application and add XML comments.
The resulting XML-file has all the comments for all public methods from the COM application.

How do I use these XML-files so that Visual Studio will give me intellisense help like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2017

I've tried copying the XML-files to the output folders that also have the interop dlls and my exe. But that didn't work and with every rebuild the XML-files are removed.

Extra info:
The COM application is MapWinGIS: https://github.com/MapWindow/MapWinGIS/tree/develop/src
The documentation project is also used to generate the API documentation: https://www.mapwindow.org/documentation/mapwingis4.9/index.html
Sample of the documentation: https://github.com/MapWindow/MapWinGIS/blob/develop/docs/Interop.MapWinGIS/Com%20Classes/GdalUtils.cs
One of the intellisense files: https://github.com/MapWindow/MapWinGIS/blob/develop/docs/AxInterop.MapWinGIS.XML

Comment: Just to make sure; you are using a wrapper to enable intellisence? That should work.

Comment: The problem is not that the XML intellisense are not created. They are. The problem is that I can't get Visual Studio to use them.

Comment: I understand.... so you are using the C# component as a wrapper, if so, that rules out the complexity of the COM component. That's what I am after. If not; I don't understand your setup. So; if you are using the C# component as wrapper, the normal C# features should apply. If so; place the XML file in the directory from which you reference the DLL.

Comment: Why is C++ more difficult to document than C#?  See the [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) tool.